# Dynamically invoking an angular material tooltip from .ts file

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've got a grid of inputs that need to behave in the same way, including showing an error state when the entered value is 0. I'm trying to show the error state with a tooltip. So I need to prevent it from displaying unless there is an error, and I would also like to set the error message dynamically (there may be other error messages in the future). I need to do this in the keyup event, but all the documentation shows disable/enable happening in the html.

```
<input #cell autocomplete="off" matInput type="number" 
[(ngModel)]="task"
(focus)="focus($event)"
(keydown)="keydown($event, i, j+1)"
(keyup)="keyup($event, task)"
#tooltip="matTooltip"
matTooltip="some error text"
[matTooltipPosition]="'after'"
matTooltipClass="mat-tooltip-error" />
```

I've added in the `#tooltip` reference as per: https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/examples

where can access showing and hiding with `tooltip.show()` and `tooltip.hide()` but I don't know how to access it from inside the keyup function in the ts file (it does not appear in event.target). I also can't do a conditional statement in the `(keyup)` event directly, so I don't understand how this can be accomplished.

Comment: just a question on the side.  wouldn't it be better to have all validation logic/validation done with reactive forms  and (custom) validators. in this approach you can use the state of the validators to generate and trigger the errors / tooltips etc. you could build more complex logic more easily

Comment: I agree, but those are not the constraints I'm working with as part of a larger team :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(keyup)="keyup($event, task, tooltip);
```

And in your TS file:

```
keyup(evt:MouseEvent,task:any,tooltip:MatTooltip) {
...
}
```

Comment: That works, thank you! Seems obvious now, but I'm still trying to convert my brain from thinking in jquery to angular.

Comment: It takes some time to get used to Angular way (including the RxJS stuff). Be careful to, after some Angular time, not start thinking in the opposite way, I mean... asking your self how to do things without Angular. All JavaScript functions and language works just the same way inside Angular Ecosystem. :D